# HSQLDB user lacks privilege or object not found error when making select statements with where

Tags: sql, database, select, hsqldb

I use SQuirrel SQL Client Version 3.5.3 and HSQLDB for my database. I have been able to specify the corresponding driver (In-memory) to it and create an Alias.

I have created a table

```
CREATE TABLE ENTRY(
NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
DESC VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (NAME))
```

and added a few lines of data into it. While statements like these work:

```
select * from ENTRY
select NAME from ENTRY
select DESC from ENTRY
```

I always get `Error: user lacks privilege or object not found"`
when adding a `where` clause to my statement, e.g. `select DESC from ENTRY where NAME=CAR`

Any help is greatly appreciated as I can slowly feel my sanity waning

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but my table name and other things were ok except *my query for VARCHAR were inside double quotes("") but it should be in single quotes('')*

**example**:
assume you have table like this which flightId is primary key[image]

now this query is wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM flights WHERE flightId="0f3ae9b3-6bb1-4c95-9394-6179555f5879"
```

while this one is ok:

```
SELECT * FROM flights WHERE flightId='0f3ae9b3-6bb1-4c95-9394-6179555f5879'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to fix this myself. I had used a wrong table name for my select statements and after changing it to the real one it worked. The only thing that confuses me is that I also used the wrong table name for my insert statements but they were executed successfully and all data is showing up in them.

Comment: I do not think that message is helpful.  I watched the logs for the Database Manager on the console and it shows that message when ever a query returns a `NullPointerException`.  The wrong table name would qualify -- What I'm stumped on is _why_ I can make a Unique Constraint (index) but can't DROP it, even though I can drop the table!

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB has default schema called PUBLIC. All SQL queries will be pointing to PUBLIC; If you have created your own schema like eg:*OWNSCHEMA* then edit the xxx.script and change the following line

```
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
```

to

```
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA OWNSCHEMA
```

Answer (score 0):

When I received the same exception the root cause was that I had a table in the SELECT clause that was not present in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

> I always get Error: user lacks privilege or object not found" when
> adding a where clause to my statement, e.g. select DESC from ENTRY
> where NAME=CAR

Yes, of course you do.
NAME is a field of the ENTRY table.  CAR isn't a field of anything.
Perhaps your WHERE clause should look like this instead:

`WHERE NAME='CAR'`

Thereby comparing a field value with a literal string value instead of trying to compare it with a nonexistent other field value.