# Getting exception - user lacks privilege or object not found error in HSQL database with java

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

I have created database using hsql and also added one table using UI interface of swingmanager in java and hsql.

Point 1:

I created data base using the following details

```
Type : HSQL Database Engine Standalone
Driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
URL: jdbc:hsqldb:file:mydb
UserName: SA
Password: SA
```

Point 2:
Have insterted some data from UI of hsql.

Point 3: hsql Connection is working

Point 4: Trying to read data using java code but getting exception saying -
user lacks privilege or object not found error

1. Similar issue -https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/mailman/message/28944633/
2. Tried with providing capital "SA" in while connecting to DB and also in code
3. As hsql is case sensitive, try query like-
   SELECT ID FROM DOMAIN
   or
   SELECT ID FROM "DOMAIN"
4. GO to this path -C:\hsqldb-2.4.1\hsqldb\data
   check that you don't have multiple copies of these files: 
   mydb.log, mydb.lck, mydb.properties, etc in your workspace
5. Tried this query in single quotes
   'SELECT ID FROM DOMAIN'
6. This link has one more solution -
   [HSQLDB user lacks privilege or object not found error when making select statements with where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323957/hsqldb-user-lacks-privilege-or-object-not-found-error-when-making-select-stateme)
7. You can try with creating different table with unique name instead of domain

   Resultset rs=stmt.executequery("Select * from testdemo");

This line throwing exception saying -user lacks privilege or object not found error

Actual Result:

> user lacks privilege or object not found error

Expected Result: It should read data from table

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common issues working with HSQLDB is the missing/wrong database alias name in the connection string. when you start the HSQLDB server with the following command,

```
@java -classpath ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:sampledb --db
```

the required connection URL is jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/***sdb***. Make sure that your new table is in the PUBLIC schema coz by default that's where the driver would look for the table. From what you have told, if you are able to query the table using the UI tool, then this is more likely your connection string problem.

If you are using the file store run mode, you can connect from within the installation e.g. C:\servers\DB\hsqldb240\bin\runManagerSwing.bat (tro the swing UI manager) using the jdbc:hsqldb:file:testdb;ifexists=true; but to connect using java, you should specify the filedb location in the connection string like jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\servers\DB\hsqldb240\testdb;ifexists=true;

Comment: I am able to query to table from UI and also connection is successful via java code. But while fetching the data from table through java code for above mentioned line i am getting issue.

Comment: This is the connection string i am using - jdbc:hsqldb:fie:testdb;ifexists=true;

Comment: This connection string (jdbc:hsqldb:fie:testdb;ifexists=true;) will work when you connect using the Swing UI app from within the installation (e.g. C:\servers\DB\hsqldb240\bin\runManagerSwing.bat) but when you connect from the java code you need to tell the driver where to find the DB file, so try changing your connection string to jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\servers\\DB\\hsqldb240\\testdb;ifexists=true; (file is mistyped as fie in your connection string)

Comment: I have connected hsql db from "runManagerSwing.bat" and used this connection string to connect to UI interface - jdbc:hsqldb:file:testdb; .................Right now problem i am facing is i can not find testdb path in my local c drive path like ths ---C:\\servers\\DB\\hsqldb240\\testdb;ifexists=true;.........could you please help where should i find this testdbpath on local machine as i am connecting via runSwingManager.bat using mentioned connection string.......

Comment: Can anyone will help me in this...as this is very urgent...Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your runManagerSwing.bat file located? C:\\servers\\DB\\hsqldb240\\testdb - was just an example, you will not find this path in your PC. can you search for testdb.properties in your computer? That can give you the location. Again the testdb dbrelated files should be available at <HSQLDB_PATH>\data\testdb and this is what you need in the connection string.